# How can I mention someone using the Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I would like to mention a username in a regular post using the Facebook C# SDK so that his name is clickable and leads to his profile. Does anyone know how to do such a thing?

Comment: Last I heard this was a known limitation of Graph API (and any framework over it such as Facebook C# SDK), but I'll let someone else give a definitive answer.

Comment: that would be great. thanks alot @JonNewman